# How can I be sure an email attached Word file with RSA certificate did not infect my MacBook?

Tags: macos, virus, phishing

I received an email from a plausible address with a Word file attached.

Stupidly, I downloaded and opened the Word file with Microsoft Word on OSX which looked like a RSA certificate file. It asked permissions for macro execution and for downloading additional language packages. I denied all but how can I be totally sure that nothing is infected?
Is there any tool to check?

Answer (score 1):

The only check possible is to run deep anti-virus scans on the computer.

Use your current anti-virus, but also use some other well-known products from the Web.
Most such products have a free scan version, some can even be launched from the browser.

Ensure you are using the right product from the right website.
Do not trust its top placement in Google search, since the hackers seem to be able
to control that.

Comment: Do u have any antivirus suggestion for osx platforms?I don't know any

Comment: You may see some suggestions [here](https://www.techradar.com/best/best-mac-antivirus-software).

Comment: I run a scan with Avast and did not find anything. I think one step closer but maybe not yet sure

Comment: In my own opinion, by denying the permission to execute the macro you have avoided the infection. If two antivirus products give the computer a clean bill, I think you can feel safe. If you want to feel even safer, you can rollback to a System Restore point from before the event (but this is probably an overkill).